# use ng-style with switch statement - angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is is possible to use ng-style along with a function returning a non-boolean value?

I wanted to color different a bg according to a property in my model and 
I managed to do that

```
<tr ng-repeat="issue in data.issues|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" ng-style="{'background-color': isToday(issue.due_date) ?  'red': 'yellow'}" >
   ...
```

controller:

```
    $scope.isToday = function (compareDate) {
        var today = $scope.today;
        return compareDate < today.getFullYear() + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' + today.getMonth();
    }
```

where the *isToday* function returns a boolean.

How can I handle the case where my function returns 3 values (or more) and I want to have 3 different background colors according to its result?

Comment: You are doing a text based comparison for date object.... which won't be proper like `2016-31-01` will be greater than `2016-2-1`

Comment: thanks Arun, but the composition of the function is not my question. I wanted to know if it is possible to use ngStyle with a function that can return 3 different values and not 2 (as a boolean)

Comment: Implement a function that get a date and return a unique rgb color based on the date , and use it as the value of the `background-color`.

Comment: @URL87, please could u provide an example of it with view and controller?

Comment: @eeadev: do you know in a head how many dates you going to have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngClass.
template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="issue in data.issues|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" ng-class="{{ myClass }}" >
```

css:

```
.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
}
```

js:

```
$scope.myClass = 'three' // or 'one', or 'two'
```

Comment: what's that? How do u pass the issue.due_date?

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/gtug5ej2/2/ see the documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to give you concept- how you can achieve what you want, please update `someFun` function according to you needs i.e. `date` etc

Following example just tries to put different classes based on condition evaluation. If you need some modifications please let me know I will do it right way.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
     
  //sample items
     $scope.items = ['One',
                     'Two',
                     'Three',
                     'Four',
                     'Five',
                     'Six',
                     'Seven',
                     'Eight',
                     'Nine'];
  //this is function where multiple condtions will be handled
  $scope.someFunc = function(index, cond){
    //some sample conditions, write here according to your requirements
    if(index >6 && index%22 && cond == 'c')
     return true;
    if(index%2 && cond == 'a')
     return true;
    if(index%3 && cond == 'b')
     return true;
    else return false;
  }
  
});
```

```css
.green{ 
  background-color:green;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color:white;
}
.blue{ 
  background-color:blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.red{ 
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{ 'blue': someFunc($index, 'a'), 'green': someFunc($index, 'b'), 'red': someFunc($index, 'c') }"> {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Happy Helping!